# Создать из двух списков один двумерный

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Имеются 2 списка с равным количеством элементов. Списки создаются в процессе парсинга - 1-ый список содержит рандомные числа, 2-ой ссылки(`<a href="somelink">...</a>`):

```
links = [<a href="somelink1"></a>, <a href="somelink2"></a>, ...]
nums = [123, 321, random-num, ...]
```

Задача - объединить два этих списка в один двумерный для последующего вывода ссылки и числа в одну строку - `123 <a href="somelink">`, т.е 3-й список должен выглядеть так:

```
list3 = [[123,<a href="somelink1">],[321,<a href="somelink2">], [nnumber,nlink] ...]
```

Я пробовал использовать функцию zip() - `z = zip(nums,links)` , но она меня не устраивает, т.к в дальнейшем может понадобиться добавить значения в каждый из рядов или новый ряд.

Интересует также, как можно упорядочить в готовом 3ем списке элементы по убыванию значений чисел, когда я пытался это сделать функцией sorted() `z = sorted(z, key=lambda tup:(tup[0]))` результат был примерно таким:
10,123,11,1101,21,2222,200 - т.е числа отсортировались, но не по значению, а по первой цифре числа.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу сортировки, вы усложняете себе жизнь — не нужно ни какой key-функции, просто

```
z = sorted(list3)
```

---

Пример:

```
sorted([[13, "aaa"], [100, "bbb"], [1, "ccc"], [3, "ddd"]])
```

выдает

> ```
> [[1, 'ccc'], [3, 'ddd'], [13, 'aaa'], [100, 'bbb']]
> ```

На счет проблемы с `zip()` я тоже не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делаю это так:

```py
>>> links = ["<a href=lnk1></a>", "<a href=lnk2></a>", "<a href=lnk3></a>"]
>>> nums = [1,123, 13]
>>> list3 = [list(x) for x in zip(nums, links)]
>>> list3
[[1, '<a href=lnk1></a>'], [123, '<a href=lnk2></a>'], [13, '<a href=lnk3></a>']]
>>> sorted(list3)
[[1, '<a href=lnk1></a>'], [13, '<a href=lnk3></a>'], [123, '<a href=lnk2></a>']]
```

Answer (score 0):

По поводу сортировки:

```
In [15]: from operator import itemgetter

In [16]: list3 = [[123, 'text_1'],[321,'text_2'], [110, 'text_3'], [11, 'text_4']]

In [17]: sorted(list3, key=itemgetter(0))
Out[17]: [[11, 'text_4'], [110, 'text_3'], [123, 'text_1'], [321, 'text_2']]
```

На счет проблемы с `zip()` не совсем понятно.

Comment: Странно, но почему-то проблема с сортировкой сохраняется, хотя код `from operator import itemgetter
links = ['txt1', 'txt2', 'txt3', 'txt4']
nums = [123, 13123, 1090, 10]
z = zip(nums, links)
z = sorted(z, key=itemgetter(0))
print(z)` в новом скрипте отрабатывает как и должен. Может ли это как-то быть связано с тем, что сортировка происходит в созданной мной функции parse(), а затем уже эта функция вызывается n раз(n соответствует количеству страниц, которые необходимо отпарсить) уже в функции main()? На счет zip пока точно не уверен, просто что-то пошло не так)

Comment: Почему-то проблема сохраняется, даже если сортировать просто список с числами-вот результат print() `['1791', '1553', '1193', '1705', '1468', '1265', '1076', '1593', '1175', '1144', '165', '196', '134', '194', '2734', '2339', '2703', '257', '299', '273', '277', '287', '217', '270', '273', '298', '211', '281', '255', '279', '251', '3949', '3938', '348', '368', '326', '368', '399', '383', '355', '313', '480', '426', '454', '489', '436', '429', '500', '568', '555', '544', '529', '578', '525', '668', '605', '600', '617', '768', '710', '799', '747', '837', '872', '828', '827', '969', '900', '977']`

Comment: Вообщем, получилось отсортировать список с числами таким способом: `people.sort(key=lambda people: int(people.split()[0]))` . Но! Если попытаться сделать это для переменной z, которая является кортежем двух списков, то появится ошибка.

Comment: @IDK Мне нудно больше данных.. Что за функция `parse()`?

Comment: `def parse(html):
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
 ul = soup.find('ul', class_='list')
 views = ul.find_all('li', class_='views')

 #parsing people count
 people = []
 for i in views:
  cnt = i.text
  cnt = cnt[cnt.find(',')+2:]
  cnt = cnt.split(" ")[0]
  people.append(cnt)   z = zip(people, links)` Вот кусок этой функции. Между вызовом функции `zip()` и циклом `for` еще 1 отдельный цикл, аналогичный циклу выше - по добавлению ссылок в список `links`. Причем список links сортируется нормально - по алфавиту, а вот со списком people происходит что-то не то.

Comment: Вообщем назрел такой вопрос: это выражение - `people.sort(key=lambda people: int(people.split()[0]), reverse=True)` работает как надо, т.е сортирует элементы по значениям, а не по 1-ой цифре, как мне сформировать параллельный запрос на список со ссылками, чтобы индексы в обоих списках совпадали? Я сделал так: `people.sort(key=lambda people: int(people.split()[0]), reverse=True)
 links.sort(key=lambda people: str(people.split()[0])) z = zip(people, links) for item in z:print(item)`  И вроде бы скрипт работает как надо, но есть у меня подозрения, что это не совсем так.